# Javascript/Jquery OOP Array inside of an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a nutshell I am making a REST call to my database and getting a list of ingredients back. The JSON looks like:

```
[{"SubItemID":1,"MainItemID":1,"SubName":"2%","MainName":"Milk"},
{"SubItemID":2,"MainItemID":1,"SubName":"Skim/Fat Free","MainName":"Milk"},
{"SubItemID":3,"MainItemID":2,"SubName":"Chedder","MainName":"Cheese"}]
```

What I want to do is transform this into a useful array that is organized as:

1. Milk

   1. 2%
   2. Skim/Fat Free
2. Cheese

   1. chedder

In addition to it being ordered like that, I want to maintain the ID associated with each item. So cheese would have "2" and chedder would have "3".

I have been able to feed the unique values of Milk and Cheese into an array but I am not sure how to proceed. Advise would be appreciated!

Here's what I have so far:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "../api/IngredientChoices",
            contentType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var _subCategories = {};
                var _mainCategories = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    if ($.inArray(item.MainName, _mainCategories) === -1) {
                        _mainCategories.push(item.MainName);
                    }
                });
                $.each(_mainCategories, function () {
                    alert(this);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you using JSON `parse()`?

Comment: @ATOzTOA I added my current Ajax code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed working answer. The data is added to an associative array.

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(obj);

d = {}

$.each(obj, function (index, item) {
    if (!(item.MainItemID in d)) {
        d[item.MainItemID] = [];
        d[item.MainItemID][0] = item.MainName;
        d[item.MainItemID][1] = {}
    }

    d[item.MainItemID][1][item.SubItemID] = item.SubName;
});

console.log(d);
```

Output:

```
Object {1: Array[2], 2: Array[2]}
1: Array[2]
    0: "Milk"
        1: "2%"
        2: "Skim/Fat Free"
2: Array[2]
    0: "Cheese"
        3: "Chedder"
```

Comment: I think OP is asking how to refactor the JSON, not how to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to edit your question. The 'useful' array you want is actually not an array. You might want this : 
[ 
     {
          name : 'Milk',
          subTypes : [ '2%', 'Fat Free'],
     },
     {
          name : 'Cheese',
          subTypes : [ 'Cheddar' ],
     }
]

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/r5ZeT/2/)

```
var data = [{"SubItemID":1,"MainItemID":1,"SubName":"2%","MainName":"Milk"},
{"SubItemID":2,"MainItemID":1,"SubName":"Skim/Fat Free","MainName":"Milk"},
{"SubItemID":3,"MainItemID":2,"SubName":"Chedder","MainName":"Cheese"}];

var ordered = {};

for(var i = data.length; i--;) {
  var mainItemID = data[i].MainItemID;
  if(!ordered[mainItemID]) {
    ordered[mainItemID] = {};
    ordered[mainItemID].MainName = data[i].MainName;
    ordered[mainItemID].MainItemID = mainItemID;
  }
  ordered[mainItemID][data[i].SubItemID] = data[i];
}

console.log(ordered);
```

And you can have a array with your object collection, that way you will be able to sort it:

```
var dataArray = [];

for(var k in ordered) {
  dataArray.push(ordered[k]);
}

console.log(dataArray);
```

If you plan more complex data parsing, or manipulation, I would recommend some model/collection framework, like: [Backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/), [SpineJS](http://spinejs.com/), or even use [webSQL](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB).

Comment: You are not getting `MainName`.